# Function determine if two sets equal in xquery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

```
$seq1 := (1,2,3)
$seq2 := (2,3,1)

fn:deep-equal ($seq1,$seq2) will return false
```

What function or functx will return true when comparing both "sets"?

Comment: How do you want duplicates handled? Are (1,2) and (1,2,1) equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deep-equal(sort($seq1), sort($seq2))` should work for that sample. But in general I think you want e.g. `empty((eg:value-except($seq1, $seq2), eg:value-except($seq2, $seq1)))` where the function `eg:value-except` is as declared in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#union-intersect-except-on-values, example  does

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare namespace eg = "http://example.com/mf";

declare option output:method 'text';
declare option output:html-version '5';

declare function eg:value-except (
  $arg1 as xs:anyAtomicType*,
  $arg2 as xs:anyAtomicType*) as xs:anyAtomicType* 
{
  fn:distinct-values($arg1[not(.=$arg2)])
};

let
  $seq1 := (1,2,3,4),
  $seq2 := (2,3,1)
return empty((eg:value-except($seq1, $seq2), eg:value-except($seq2, $seq1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use maps: `deep-equal(f:to-map($seq1), f:to-map($seq2))` where `f:to-map($seq)` does `map:merge($seq!map{., 0})`. But the details depend on how you want to handle duplicates.